# Как обновить git через консоль на MacOS?

Tags: git, macos

Если я правильно понимаю, то сам git нельзя обновить коммандой `git update` или `git self-update`.

По запросу `git --version` вижу `git version 2.31.0`.

В сети рекомендуют обновлять его через brew коммандой `brew upgrade git`. Он там обновился и выдает теперь `Warning: git 2.35.1 already installed`.

Получается у меня 2 версии гита установлены? Можно ли как-то сделать версию из brew основной? Ну или есть ли какой-то еще способ обновить версию 2.31.0 не скачивая инсталятор с сайта, а сделать это через консоль?

Кстати, `which git` выдает `/usr/local/bin/git`, и это, как я понимаю, как раз-таки версия из brew?

Answer (score 1):

Нашел решение. Командой

```
brew link --overwrite git
```

все заменилось и теперь в

```
git --version
```

показывается `git version 2.35.1`.